# Error in Sql Server 2005 Express Edition while consuming a WCF web service 

Tags: sql-server-2005, wcf

My SQl Server data base is located in another machine and WCF service and client is on another machine.

While I consume this service ,which in turn access the Sql server to fetch data and return to the client, it gives following error :

Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection.

This error comes when I open the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are:

- Running the WCF service in IIS
- Using a connection string that spesifies trusted connection
- Default web.config and IIS settings

In this case it will be the identity of the application pool that will be used to access that database. By default this is a local user so it will not have access to the database.

There are several ways you can fix this:

- A connection string that specifies user name and password
- Change the identity of the app pool to a domain user that has access to the database
- spesify impersonate = true and call the WCF service with a user that has access to the database
  ...

**EDIT 1**

The error that you are getting after you turn off IIS anonymous authentication is due to you not sending user information with your request, which means that you get a challenge response back. This requires changes to your WCF configuration. In your case the easiest thing to do is to specify the username and passord in the connection string.

Comment: Yes your assumption is true in my case.
Please tell me where and how can I specify impersonate = true ??
and how to change the identity of the app pool to a domain user that has access to the database

Comment: Can SQL EXPRESS support sql server authentication?

Comment: Yes it supports sql server authentication

Comment: One strange thing that I noticed that when I choose "Use Visual Studio Development Server option" in WCF Service application properies page -> Web. I am not getting any error, but when I choose "Use Local IIS Web Server" option in the WCF Service application project and create a virtual directory and intialiae the client with URL like http:/10.12.12.25/MyService/Service1.svc then I will get "Login failed for user ''. The user is not associated with a trusted SQL Server connection" error while opening the connection ..

Comment: The same problem is described in the link below:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/a42be75e-18f2-4c8c-be28-752c55626ac6

Comment: I am giving the user name and password in the connection string but still I am getting this error